# AngularJS Get not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.  I have a .net MVC WebAPI Restful app running on a IIS server.  When I query the api with http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/project  I get:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Glenn Block","Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Dan Roth","Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]
```

I created a ProjectCtrl (in a separate empty project) that looks like this:

```
angular.module('Project', ['ngResource']);

function ProjectCtrl($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.project = $resource('http://192.168.1.221/api/project'
    );
    $scope.project.get(function (data) {
        console.log('success, got data: ', data);
    }, function (err) {
        alert('request failed');
    });
}
```

I always get a failure.  I addressed CORS issues on the server and the request header contains

```
Access-Control-Request-He...    x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
```

What I find odd is that when I look in firebug it does NOT do a get but rather shows Option project with a status of 200

I am not sure what I missing.

Comment: Does the first parameter in the `get` need to be an empty `{}` object? If so, you `(err)` callback is actually your returned data.  Just a guess.

Comment: I just tried this and no change.  I did however, add these lines to the top of the ProjectCtrl...var myApp = angular.module('Project', ['ngResource']);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
 and it now does a get and I see the data.  I do get a error in console - Error: a.push is not a function

Comment: Bummer, I'll delete answer if it's wrong.  Don't want this to go unanswered.

Comment: There were several parts to this answer and all the input was valuable in solving.  dnc253 helped with the last piece regarding the query.  The addition of the config setting were also required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mentioned in your comment, "Error: a.push is not a function", is because your response is an array. With `$resource`, use the `query` function when your response is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first parameter of the resource call should be resource-based params.  If you have none, pass an empty object `{}` as the first parameter:

```
$scope.project.get({},function (data) {
    console.log('success, got data: ', data);
}, function (err) {
    alert('request failed');
});
```

My guess is that your `err` object is actually the successfully returned data.  If I'm wrong, tell me and I'll delete!